# Integrating a function with Python (sympy, quad) where the result is another function I want to plot

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, numerical-integration, quad

I want to integrate a function using python, where the output is a new function rather than a numerical value.  For example, I have the equation (from Arnett 1982 -- analytical description of a supernova):

```
def A(z,tm,tni):
     y=tm/(2*tni)
     tm=8.8             # diffusion parameter
     tni=8.77           # efolding time of Ni56
     return 2*z*np.exp((-2*z*y)+(z**2))
```

I want to then find the integral of A, and then plot the results.  First, I naively tried scipy.quad:

```
def Arnett(t,z,tm,tni,tco,Mni,Eni,Eco): 
     x=t/tm
     Eni=3.90e+10       # Heating from Ni56 decay
     Eco=6.78e+09       # Heating from Co56 decay
     tni=8.77           # efolding time of Ni56
     tco=111.3          # efolding time of Co56
     tm=8.8             # diffusion parameter 
     f=integrate.quad(A(z,tm,tni),0,x)      #integral of A
     h=integrate.quad(B(z,tm,tni,tco),0,x)  #integral of B
     g=np.exp((-(x/tm)**2))
     return Mni*g*((Eni-Eco)*f+Eco*h)
```

Where B is also a pre-defined function (not presented here).  Both A and B are functions of z, however the final equation is a function of time, t.  (I believe that it is herein I am causing my code to fail.)

The integrals of A and B run from zero to x, where x is a function of time t. Attempting to run the code as it stands gives me an error: "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()".

So after a short search I thought that maybe sympy would be the way to go.  However I am failing with this as well.

I wonder if anyone has a helpful suggestion how to complete this task please?

Many thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate A analytically. Assuming I'm not missing something silly due to being up way too late, does the following help?

```
import sympy as sy
sys.displayhook = sy.pprint
A, y, z, tm, t, tni = sy.symbols('A, y, z, tm, t, tni')
A = 2*z*sy.exp(-2*z*y + z**2)
expr = sy.integrate(A, (z,0,t)) # patience - this takes a while
expr
# check:
(sy.diff(expr,t).simplify() - A.replace(z,t)).simplify()
# thus, the result:
expr.replace(y,tm/(2*tni)).replace(t,t/tm)
```

The last line yields the integral of your A function in analytic form, though it does require evaluating the imaginary error function (which you can do with scipy.special.erfi()).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are lambda expression (if i understood correctly what you said.. see [here](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) for extra information and some examples on lambda functions).

What they allow you to do is define an anonymous function in A and return it so that you get your B function, should work something like this:

```
 def A(parameters):
     return lambda x: x * parameters # for simplicity i applied a multiplication
                                     # but you can apply anything you want to x
 B = A(args)
 x = B(2)
```

Hope I could provide you with a decent response!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you get comes from an incorrect call to scipy.integrate.quad:

- The first argument needs to be just the function name, integration is then performed over the first variable of this function. The values of the other variables can be passed to the function via the args keyword.
- The output of scipy.integrate.quad contains not only the value of the integral, but also an error estimate. So a tuple of 2 values is returned!

In the end the following function should work:

```
def Arnett(t, z, Mni, tm=8.8, tni=8.77, tco=111.3, Eni=3.90e+10,
           Eco=6.78e+09): 
  x=t/tm
  f,err=integrate.quad(A,0,x,args=(tm,tni))      #integral of A
  h,err=integrate.quad(B,0,x,args=(tm,tni,tco))  #integral of B
  g=np.exp((-(x/tm)**2))
  return Mni*g*((Eni-Eco)*f+Eco*h)
```

But an even better solution would probably be integrating A and B analytically and then evaluating the expression [as murison suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31855296/2358845).